# JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR while using json_decode, none of the classic solutions work

Tags: php, json, decode

I've been trying to fix this thing for an entire day already and couldn't get it to work. Something which is supposed to be easy.

The problem is, I do a GET request to this URL: http://api.champion.gg/stats?api_key=851a15d4f271849f3beee664ea03db3b

Then, I try to convert the result to a JSON format using the PHP function json_decode. I do it like this:

```
$httpResponse = drupal_http_request('http://api.champion.gg/stats?api_key=851a15d4f271849f3beee664ea03db3b');
$data = $httpResponse->data;
$datas = json_decode($data);
var_export($datas);
$error = json_last_error_msg();
echo "Error = $error";
```

And the error message returns "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"

I have already tried using stripslashes, deleting BOM, html_entities, deleting some initial characters and none of them have worked.

Comment: Thanks for the API key, btw. It looks like the API isn't managing to output the entire document before the connection is aborted. Contact your provider. Don't forget to get a new API key while you're at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set "Accept-Encoding" header to "gzip, deflate", otherwise the response is truncated.

```
$httpResponse = drupal_http_request('http://api.champion.gg/stats?api_key=851a15d4f271849f3beee664ea03db3b', array('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflater'));
$data = gzdecode($httpResponse->data);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. I was definitely looking at it by the wrong side. May I ask, what exactly did you do and why was that being the problem?

Comment: Firstly I checked a response in my browser and correct JSON was returned. Then I just checked a response without sending any header and noticed it's truncated. So the reason is wrong server configuration.